# Typescript Module System setting not working

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have an existing typescript project and I would like to set the module type to System.  I can do this in the project properties.  However, when the compiler compiles to js, it's always in the AMD format (define...).

This makes no sense.  No matter what I set the setting at, it always compiles to AMD, even when I set it to none.

However, I try to duplicate this in a test project, and then the module system setting works as expected.

How can I debug this?  I don't want to have to wipe out the project just to get the setting to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the .ts files were not part of the project, thus they do not use the project settings. (The files were visible in the Solution Explorer as the "Show all files" was checked.)

Once included, it worked as expected.